# How does a servo motor remember its starting position?

Tags: arduino, voltage, power, current

[image]

If I program this servo motor rotate 0  to 90 degrees, and I disconnect the USB cable (power supply) maybe at 45 degrees. When I reconnect the USB, the servo motor rotates back to 0 degrees to where it started with very precise initial position. It seems like it can remember its initial starting position. How does this servo motor remember its initial position magically?

Comment: Ah, the servo does not remember. It is the mcu, Arduino or Rpi. that remembers.

Comment: Analog servos have a potentiometer that provides absolute position feedback.  Digital servos have a quadrature encoder with an index channel to determine the home position.

Answer (score 6):

A servo of that type doesn't 'remember its starting position'. The hardware 'knows its position at all times' as it has a potentiometer connected to the output shaft, and will adjust its position to whatever it's being controlled to.

When you reconnect a USB port, who knows what software tricks are being performed at that point. If you can specify it, then the software could be made to do it. It could control the servo to a default position, or position remembered in a scratch file, or anything else.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

*Figure 1. A butchered model servo actuator. Image source: [Sparkfun](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/hobby-servo-tutorial/all).*

The brown disk with three terminals is a potentiometer driven directly by the output shaft. A known voltage is applied between the ends of the track and the voltage on the wiper pin is analogous to the servo position. This does not require memory during a power cycle.

A web image search for `model servo teardown` will yield plenty of other photos. It might be interesting to consider how the various manufacturers handle backlash in the connection between the driveshaft and the potentiometer. (Backlash would mean that any play or looseness in the fit would allow some reverse movement of the shaft to take place before the potentiometer moved.)